# How to fix _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) -Flutter (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I am trying to get the user's profile picture, name and email but I keep on getting the `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)` error. This is where I get my error:

```
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;//at the end is where the error is (the '!')
```

Code:

```
        Column(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 52,
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              user.displayName!,
              style: titleStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              user.email!,
              style: titleStyle,
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I've tried moving the `!` around but it just throws the error somewhere else then. I've tried implementing `??/?` on some places but to also no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `currentUser` is null, you need to accept null and handle it properly like.

```dart
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
// now `user` can accept null and the title error will be gone
```

Next thing comes when you are using it.

```dart
if(user?.photoURL!=null) CircleAvatar(....
```

Find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).

Comment: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' @YeasinSheikh

Comment: after checking `if(user?.photoURL!=null)` you can add null-assert `user.photoURL!)`

Answer (score 0):

After watching some videos I figured that it was just a wrong approach and there are better and easier ways of doing it.

```
final controller = Get.put(LoginController());
final _googleSignin = GoogleSignIn();
var googleAccount = Rx<GoogleSignInAccount?>(null);
```

```
login() async {
    googleAccount.value = await _googleSignin.signIn();
  }
```

```
Column(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 52,
              backgroundImage:
                  NetworkImage(controller.googleAccount.value?.photoUrl ?? ''),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              controller.googleAccount.value?.displayName ?? '',
              style: subHeadingStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(
              controller.googleAccount.value?.email ?? '',
              style: subHeadingStyle,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

// 1. Check if the variable is null before using it:

`if (variable != null) { // use variable safely } else { // handle null case }`

// 2. Use the null-aware operator (`?.`) instead of the null check operator (`!`) to avoid the error altogether:

`variable?.doSomething();`

// 3. Use the null-coalescing operator (`??`) to provide a default value when the variable is null:

`final value = variable ?? defaultValue;`